# How can we get this output?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, nested-lists

We all know that 20.1>20 but when i compile this code see what result do i get

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihMoJ.png)

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr=[]
    max
    for i in range(int(input("Range: "))):
        name = input("Name: ")
        score = float(input("Score: "))
        item=[name,score]
        arr.append(item)
    arr.sort(reverse=True)
    print(arr)
```

i expected a arrangement of 40,20.1,20.01,20.001, etc but  i got 40,20,20.1,20.01, 20.001 etc

Comment: It's sorting by `name` because that's the first key in `item`.  If you had two items with the same name, it would use `score` as a secondary sort key, but all the names are different.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort key is not correct. A working code looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr=[]
    max
    for i in range(int(input("Range: "))):
        name = input("Name: ")
        score = float(input("Score: "))
        item=[name,score]
        arr.append(item)
    arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1] , reverse=True)
    print(arr)
```